# How to create a table from each nested node of an xml using pyspark

Tags: xml, scala, pyspark, databricks

I have a nested XML structure as below-

```
<parent>
<root1 detail = "something">
    <ID type="typeA">id1</ID>
    <ID type="typeB">id2</ID>
    <ID type="typeC">id3</ID>
</root1>

<root2 detail = "something">
    <ID type="typeA">id1</ID>
    <ID type="typeB">id2</ID>
    <ID type="typeC">id3</ID>
</root2>
<parent>
```

I want to create 2 tables out of it with columns and data as follows-

Schema:

```
detail string
ID string
type string
```

Records:

```
detail        ID     type
something     id1   typeA
something     id2   typeB
something     id3   typeC
```

I have tried using

```
   spark.read.format(file_type) \
      .option("rootTag", "root1") \
      .option("rowTag", "ID") \
      .load(file_location)
```

But this produces only description (string) and ID(array) as columns.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume that because this question has the pyspark tag that you're working in python, but then it is also tagged with scala, so are you flexible with which language the answer is in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the trick is to extract the `ID` and `type` by their names (`_VALUE` and `_TYPE`) in the StructField that is in the column called "ID" that comes out from reading in the xml file:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, col

dfs = []

n = 2

for i in range(1,n+1):

    df = spark.read.format('xml') \
              .option("rowTag","root{}".format(i))\
              .load('file.xml')

    df = df.select([explode('ID'),'_detail'])\
           .withColumn('ID',col('col').getItem('_VALUE'))\
           .withColumn('type',col('col').getItem('_TYPE'))\
           .drop('col')\
           .withColumnRenamed('_detail','detail')
   
    dfs.append(df)
    
    df.show()

# +---------+---+-----+
# |   detail| ID| type|
# +---------+---+-----+
# |something|id1|typeA|
# |something|id2|typeB|
# |something|id3|typeC|
# +---------+---+-----+
# 
# +---------+---+-----+
# |   detail| ID| type|
# +---------+---+-----+
# |something|id1|typeA|
# |something|id2|typeB|
# |something|id3|typeC|
# +---------+---+-----+
```

And if you don't want to have to specify the number of tables manually (which is controlled by the variable `n` in the code above) then you could run this code first:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

tree = ElementTree.parse("file.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

children = root.getchildren()

n = 0

for child in children:
    ElementTree.dump(child)
    n+=1

print("n = {}".format(n))

# <root1 detail="something">
#     <ID type="typeA">id1</ID>
#     <ID type="typeB">id2</ID>
#     <ID type="typeC">id3</ID>
# </root1>
# 
# <root2 detail="something">
#     <ID type="typeA">id1</ID>
#     <ID type="typeB">id2</ID>
#     <ID type="typeC">id3</ID>
# </root2>
# n = 2
```

Comment: Its throwing " Can&#39;t extract value from col#1225: need struct type but got string;" error

Comment: What do you get when you do `df = spark.read.format('xml').option("rowTag","root1").load('file.xml')` (replacing 'file.xml' with your filename) and then `df.printSchema()`? 
I get: 

root
 |-- ID: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _VALUE: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _detail: string (nullable = true)

Comment: Also .option("rowTag","root").option("rootTag","root")  i need to add rootTag without which its giving error "root tag must be present"

Comment: i get root
 |-- ID: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- detail: string (nullable = true)

Comment: Got the issue. I have to enter maven co ordinate and the com.databricks.cml-spark will be installed, otherwise some other version of spark was installed. Now its giving same schema as yours